# Get proper value of hours from the String

Tags: java, time

I need to get the proper value of `hours` from a time string.  Here is sample code:

```
String startTime = "10:00";
int hours = Integer.valueOf(startTime.substring(0,1));
```

The problem is that for this example, `hours` is equal to 1 instead of 10.  As another example, with `startTime = "01:00"`, then `hours` is equal to 0 instead of 1. How can I properly determine the hours as an integer from the string?

Comment: hint: you want a substring of length 2 :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String[] hm = startTime.split(":");
```

`hm[0]` has the hour part, and `hm[1]` has the minutes.

Comment: whoops i forgot about String.split :p

Answer (score 1):

You are only getting the first character of the string, try `startTime.substring(0, 2)`, although perhaps a less brittle approach (just in case your time strings do not always have two digits specifying the hour value, you could use a regular expression: `^(\\d+):` and extracting the matched text

Answer (score 0):

```
String startTime = "10:00";
System.out.println(startTime.substring(0, startTime.indexOf(':')));
```

Comment: hint: you *also* want a substring of length 2.

Comment: I had copied the OP's code above the solution I meant to provide.  I took it out for clarity

Answer (score 0):

the first parameter of the `substring()` method is the begin Index of so actually you were saying in your code get me the sub string from zero to one which is  1 in case you should use

```java
  String startTime = "10:00";
  int hours = Integer.valueOf(startTime.substring(0,2));
  System.out.println(hours);
```

you can use some other ways like `SimpleDateFormat` to parse both strings to `Date` and then compare two dates using date helper methods like `after()` , `before()` or `equal()`

```java
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
Date date = formatter.parse("10:00");
system.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ultimately end up doing Time stuff with this, I would recommend the use of the JDKs  DateFormat, Date, and Calendar classes.

```
public class TimeFromStringTest {
    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        try {
            doTest( "10:00", 10, 0 );
            doTest( "10:10", 10, 10 );
            doTest( "23:58", 23, 58 );
            doTest( "1:01", 1, 1 );
            doTest( "24:61", 1, 1 );
        } catch ( ParseException e ) {
            fail( String.format( "unexpected exception %s", e ) );
        }
    }
    private void doTest( String candidate, int expectedHours, int expectedMins ) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mm" );
        Date result = df.parse( candidate );
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime( result );
        assertEquals( expectedHours, cal.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ) );
        assertEquals( expectedMins, cal.get( Calendar.MINUTE ) );
    }
}
```